# Dynamic batch mode for kafka spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm working on a reactive spring boot 3.1.6 project (spring-cloud-dependencies 2022.0.4)  and I would like to have a consumer that can be toggled between batch enabled/disabled. Currently I have the following consumer setup:

```
@Component
public class MyMessageHandler implements Consumer<Flux<List<InputMessage>>> {

    @Override
    public void accept(Flux<List<InputMessage>> messages) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and then the following application properties

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=myMessageHandler
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.myMessageHandler-in-0=my-messages-in
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-messages-in.destination=Some.Topic.Definition

#i want to be able to disable batch mode here
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-messages-in.consumer.batch-mode=true
```

As far as I know I cannot simply disable it in the configuration but still keep the Consumer definition as is. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-messages-in.consumer.batch-mode` does not work, but need to use the original consumer name - `myMessageHandler-in-0`?